# check permissions aix script

Tags: ksh, aix

Hello I try to write script to make this "If the file exists Must be owned by a system user and group.  Permissions for other must be r-x or more restrictive."

Aix systems 7.2

```
#MODULE BODY
file_path="/bin/ssh-add"

if [ -e $file_path ];
then 
    user=`istat $file_path | grep Owner: | awk '{print $2}'`
    uid=`id -u $user`

    if [ $uid -lt 500 ];
    then
        permissions=`istat $file_path | grep Owner: | awk '{print $2}' `

        if [ $permissions -le 755 ];
        then 
            compliant="Yes"
            actual_value='User = '$user', Permissions = '$permissions
        else
            compliant="No"
            actual_value="Bad permissions"
        fi;
    else 
        compliant="No"
        actual_value="Not system user"
    fi;
else 
   compliant="Yes"
   actual_value="NA" 
fi;
# SCRIPT RESULT
echo :::$module_id:::$compliant:::$actual_value:::
echo " === End of $module_id module === "
```

Comment: Nice script, what is the question here? You did not test the group id. What if the user is not system but belongs to system group? And permission 722 < 733 < 755 and allows write access.

Comment: `istat` is OK, but this is the point at which I'd consider switching to perl; [this is one example, for inspiration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291183/117549)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `find` command with `-perm` options.
See documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm).

With the following command you can verify the file has no write permission to others.

```
find $file_path -perm o-w
```

With the following command you can verify the file has no write permission to group.

```
find $file_path -perm g-w
```

With the following command you can verify the file has no write permission to group nor others.

```
find $file_path -perm go-w
```